# Why switching from Debug/Release mode causes projects fail to load?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Consider such case, you create a solution (C# code) with 2 projects A and B in Debug mode. Everything is fine, you would like to check it in Release mode, so you switch to it, and once you do it Visual Studio shows warning (for me on random) that project "B" failed to load.

I see this behavior solution after solution after solution. I have to unload those "failed" projects and reload them again. And it works. However it is completely bizarre and worse -- time consuming.

What is the cause of this? I am asking because maybe I could fix it systematically.

**Update**

When I switch back to mode that worked a second ago, it again cannot load some projects (the same as before). So in short, only last build mode works, when I switch to the other one I have failed projects.

sln file (3 projects):

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 14
VisualStudioVersion = 14.0.25420.1
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Tools", "Tools\Tools.csproj", "{39AF8EA1-93D1-46FF-A00E-DD5303B29C92}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Wpf.Tools", "Wpf.Tools\Wpf.Tools.csproj", "{B855F797-84A2-4CA5-9F24-0EAA34016359}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Wpf.Controls", "Wpf.Controls\Wpf.Controls.csproj", "{E93AE909-EE0B-4948-9C1B-D5546FECEFCB}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {39AF8EA1-93D1-46FF-A00E-DD5303B29C92}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {39AF8EA1-93D1-46FF-A00E-DD5303B29C92}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {39AF8EA1-93D1-46FF-A00E-DD5303B29C92}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {39AF8EA1-93D1-46FF-A00E-DD5303B29C92}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {B855F797-84A2-4CA5-9F24-0EAA34016359}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {B855F797-84A2-4CA5-9F24-0EAA34016359}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {B855F797-84A2-4CA5-9F24-0EAA34016359}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {B855F797-84A2-4CA5-9F24-0EAA34016359}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {E93AE909-EE0B-4948-9C1B-D5546FECEFCB}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {E93AE909-EE0B-4948-9C1B-D5546FECEFCB}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {E93AE909-EE0B-4948-9C1B-D5546FECEFCB}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E93AE909-EE0B-4948-9C1B-D5546FECEFCB}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

one of those 3 csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{39AF8EA1-93D1-46FF-A00E-DD5303B29C92}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Tools</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Tools</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.Core, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Reactive.Core.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.Interfaces, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Reactive.Interfaces.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Interfaces.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.Linq, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Reactive.Linq.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.Linq.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Reactive.PlatformServices, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94bc3704cddfc263, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.3.0.0\lib\net45\System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="LogHelper.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: can you post an example .sln + .csproj's that can provoke this behavior? Usually 'cannot load' means that something in those files is wrong but just reloading usually doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik, sure, see updated post. I also try to recreate this behavior from scratch to see what is tipping point -- source control (TFS), Nuget, amount of code, or files etc. At the moment of writing I didn't find out.